# Nautilus "context menu" spanish "accent" error

Tags: unity, nautilus, menu

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 Unity (4.4.0-34-generic x86_64), Spanish Mexico. After install the Nautilus tool "nautilus-image-converter" my context menu on Nautilus shows some grammar (accent) errors on the options of this tools. Other words are correct written on the menu "Im**á**genes" only this "new" options are wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: nautilus-image-converter]

Comment: Go to System Settings > Language Support and a dialog will mostly pop up if you need to install additional language packages. That may fix it. If dialog doesn't show, then is something else.

Comment: Because other words in the menu are correctly displayed. May be actually a problem of text codification (UTF-8, Western ISO 123 and that stuff) in the script that has the translated strings for menu entries of nautilus-image-converter.

Comment: I've done the " Language Support" update, but do not work, I'll keep looking for fix.